# No wifi shown in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I am currently using windows 8.1 in my laptop. When I installed it there was some issue with the wifi . I couldn't connect to my wifi because it was showing very weak signal.And the other wifi are also not shown in my laptop.

Then I installed the latest driver and the range of my home wifi is fixed but still it don't show any other wifi around me which is shown by my mobile phone

the wireless adapter of my laptop is 
Ralink RT5390R 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter

Can anyone help me????

Comment: Get a trial version of inSSider Office (Metageek) and see if it shows live access points?  Your Wi-Fi card ("N") should show most points

Comment: its only showing my wifi

Comment: Try running TCP/IP Reset and restart when done, test: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Comment: nothing happened also the range again decreased

Comment: Try a USB Wireless card to see if a different card will help you with this.

Comment: using usb wireless card shows the network

Comment: That means the card you were first trying probably has some kind of defect.

Comment: Are you happy with the USB Wireless card? And if so and if I post that as an answer, will you accept it?

Comment: yes sure you can